# function that returns a string

Tags: objective-c

Silly as it may sound, I am trying to write a simple function in objective-c which returns a string and displays it, the following code nearly works but I can't get printf to accept the functions return value ...

```
NSString* getXMLElementFromString();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf(getXMLElementFromString());
    return NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
}

NSString* getXMLElementFromString() {
    NSString* returnValue;
    returnValue = @"Hello!";
    return returnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that printf can handle an NSString.  Try somethign like:

```
 printf ("%s\n", [getXMLElementFromString()cString]);
```

Comment: I still would argue using `NSLog()` over `printf()` if you're going to be doing any serious Cocoa work.

Comment: Prefer `-UTF8String` over `-cString` — check the NSString documentation.

Answer (score 5):

`NSString*` is not equivalent to a traditional C string, which is what `printf` would expect. To use `printf` in such a way you'll need to leverage an NSString API to get a null-terminated string out of it:

```
printf("%s", [getXMLElementFromString() UTF8String]);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, marvellous.

Answer (score 2):

You should instead use `NSLog()` which takes a string (or a format string) as a parameter.

You could use either

```
NSLog(getXMLElementFromString());
```

or

```
NSLog(@"The string: %@", getXMLElementFromString());
```

Where the `%@` token specifies an Objective-C object (in this case an NSString). `NSLog()` works essentially the same as `printf()` when it comes to format strings, only it will also accept the object token.

Comment: The first form should almost always be avoided -- if an attacker can every specify a format string, you can get screwed over real fast.